# receive file via websocket and initiate download dialog

Tags: javascript, html, download, filesystems, websocket

my HTML5 web application receives a file as binary data via a websocket. Is there any way to initiate a file download dialog (via javascript) to save the received data to the users disk?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You need to build a dataUri and open a new window with this. Specific mimetypes can trigger the browser's automatic save as dialog.

Example data uri:  `"data:application/octet-stream,base64" + base64binary`

Comment: +1 Good thought, it even seems to work: http://jsbin.com/acohaz There are [some browser compatibility issues](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri) -- not least that not even IE9 supports using `data:` URIs this way yet -- but it's the only game in town if you really need to have the data held client-side and then initiate the download window.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet, no. The new [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) currently only covers reading. **Update**: See [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9871467/157247) if you only need to do this on [cutting-edge (and to date, non-IE) browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri), where you can do it with the `data:` URI scheme.

The usual way to do this would be to receive the file via HTTP into a hidden iframe using `Content-Disposition: attachment` to trigger the file download dialog, rather than receiving it via a web socket.