# How to trigger browser download from Node.JS socket stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

my node.js app connects through `var socket = net.createConnection(port, ip);` to download a file from another server. As soon as connection is made the server sends the file as data.

I catch it then by doing

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {

}).on('connect', function() {

}).on('end', function() {
console.log('DONE');
});
```

My initial goal is, to download the file using the method above and at the same time give the bytes to the client's browser as a downloadable file. For example: user clicks a button on the site which triggers the server-side download function and the user gets the file-save prompt. Node.JS then downloads the file from the remote server and at the same time gives each new byte to the user at the browser client. Is this possible? I imagine it would need to send headers of octet-stream to trigger file transfer between browser Node.JS. But how?

**Update**

Now I tried the code below with the help of the answer below:

```
app.get('/download', function (req, res) {

res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + "afile.txt");
res.setHeader('Content-Length', "12468")

var socket = net.createConnection(1024, "localhost");
console.log('Socket created.');
socket.on('data', function(data) {

    socket.pipe(res)

}).on('connect', function() {
// // Manually write an HTTP request.
// socket.write("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
}).on('end', function() {
    console.log('DONE');
    socket.end();
});

 });
```

The data is being sent to the user's browser as a download, but the end result is a broken file. I checked the contents within and it seeems that something along the process causes the file to corrupt. 
I think now I have to write byte per byte? rather than doing socket.pipe?

Comment: You can't do that, but you can receive the whole file in memory using sockets and then make the user download the file using a data URI. Like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server. Streaming the file directly for the user to download however isn't possible using websockets.

Comment: File download is only avaialable over http. That interface is not there for websocket as sending file over it is yet to be standardised. See another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871357/receive-file-via-websocket-and-initiate-download-dialog.

Comment: You are mixing on('data') and pipe. Your first chunk of data is lost when you attach `.pipe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [content-disposition](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html) header in your http response:

```
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=genome.jpeg; modification-date="Wed, 12 Feb 1997 16:29:51 -0500"'
  });
  yourDataStream.pipe(response);
```

see [RFC2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt)

Comment: The file is being sent over websocket.

Comment: why can't you serve it over http?

Comment: You can but that is not what OP is asking for.

Comment: I don't see reference to websockets in the question. Everything in question is possible via plain old http/ajax

Comment: Sorry, may be you're right. I assumed the code in question that catches file runs on browser. Otherwise you answer it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may want this:

```
app.get('/download', function (req, res) {
  res.attachment('afile.txt');
  require('http').get('http://localhost:1234/', function(response) {
    response.pipe(res);
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    res.send(500, err.message);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
by doing res.write(d) i was able to direct the bytes from the other connection to the user browser download.

```
app.get('/download', function (req, res) {

res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + "afile.jpg");
res.setHeader('Content-Length', "383790");
res.setHeader('Content-Type','image/jpeg');

var socket = net.createConnection(1024, "localhost");
console.log('Socket created.');
//socket.setEncoding("utf8");
socket.on('data', function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    res.write(d);
}).on('connect', function() {
// // Manually write an HTTP request.
// socket.write("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
}).on('end', function() {
    console.log('DONE');
    socket.end();
});


});
```