# How can I initiate a file download of client-side data and specify its file name?

Tags: javascript, download

I have been looking for a way to initiate a file download of data that only exists within the code executing on the user's browser (as opposed to initiating a download from the server), and indicate the file name in the process.

A search of StackOverflow turns up a number of promising posts that don't quite do what I need.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871357/receive-file-via-websocket-and-initiate-download-dialog) answer is not IE-compatible and doesn't allow specifying a file name anyway.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473932/browser-html-force-download-of-image-from-src-dataimage-jpegbase64) question provides a few ways to initiate downloads, but the answers that allow specifying a file name are not IE compatible and require user interaction, while other answers don't allow specifying a file name.

Is there a way to initiate a file download from JavaScript that:

- Downloads client-side data
- Does not require the user to manually initiate the download
- Allows specifying the filename of the downloaded file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching around and trying approaches from various places, I was able to come up with the following.

The `tryAnchorDownload()` approach should work on modern versions of FireFox and Chrome, and is a cleaned-up version of code provided [in this forum post](http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/285618-output-byte-array-pdf-javascript.html).

The `trySaveAsDownload()` approach should theoretically work on any major modern browser, though Safari may not respect the specified file name. It requires the [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library and some browsers may need the [Blob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js) polyfill.

You can call the main function here like this:

```
initiateFileDownload(bytes, "myFile.txt");
```

where `bytes` is a `Uint8Array` of the file's bytes.

```
function byteArrayToBase64(bytes) {
    var chArray = Array.prototype.map.call(bytes, 
                     function (byte) { return String.fromCharCode(byte); });

    return window.btoa(chArray.join(""));
}

var octetStreamMimeType = "application/octet-stream";

function tryAnchorDownload(fileBytes, fileName) {
    var aElement = document.createElement("a"),
        event;

    if ("download" in aElement) {
        aElement.setAttribute("download", fileName);
        aElement.href = "data:" + octetStreamMimeType + 
                        ";base64," + byteArrayToBase64(fileBytes);

        document.body.appendChild(aElement);
        event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        event.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                             false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        aElement.dispatchEvent(event);
        document.body.removeChild(aElement);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function trySaveAsDownload(fileBytes, fileName) {
    var blob;

    if (window.saveAs) {
        blob = new Blob([fileBytes], { type: octetStreamMimeType });

        saveAs(blob, fileName);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// fileBytes is a Uint8Array
function initiateFileDownload(fileBytes, fileName) {
    return tryAnchorDownload(fileBytes, fileName) ||
           trySaveAsDownload(fileBytes, fileName);
}
```

A more thorough (and probably more efficient) alternative to the `byteArrayToBase64()` function above can be found [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#Solution_.232_.E2.80.93_rewriting_atob%28%29_and_btoa%28%29_using_TypedArrays_and_UTF-8).