# Downloading file using javascript not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, download, mozilla

This how my code works.
When I clicked the button, it will download the file.
My code is working in Google Chrome but not working in Mozilla Firefox.

Here are my codes

HTML

```
<button type='Button' onClick='dlpdf("http://www.energy.umich.edu/sites/default/files/pdf-sample.pdf")'>Download</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function dlpdf(fileURL){

    if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
        var save = document.createElement('a');

        //alert(fileURL);

        save.href = fileURL;
        save.target = '_blank';
        save.download = fileURL || 'unknown';


        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
        save.dispatchEvent(event);
        (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
    }


}
```

Comment: Might this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445351/how-can-i-initiate-a-file-download-of-client-side-data-and-specify-its-file-name

Comment: w/o js: `<a download=sample.pdf href="http://www.energy.umich.edu/sites/default/files/pdf-sample.pdf">Download</button>`

Comment: @dandavis not working :)

Comment: @mayne: then you can't do it; the linked files need to be on-site or CORS-ready, and PDFs requires a bit extra CORS above html files...

Comment: Hi guys. thanks for helping. I get this code and it works

Comment: function exportToCsv(file) {
       window.open(escape(file));
}
 <button onclick="exportToCsv('path.pdf')">export to CSV</button>